# Arrays to database

Tags: php, arrays, database

I have a php file(users.php) which I save the user info. Every time I update or add employee I need to open the file in text editor and make some changes. This is the sample lists of employees in `$users array`.

```
$users = array(
    '001' => array('id'=>'001', 'name'=>'first lastname', 'dept'=>'Sales', 'position'=>'Lead Team', 'rate'=>'800', 'dayoff'=>'SUN'),
    '002' => array('id'=>'002', 'name'=>'sec lastname', 'dept'=>'Sales', 'position'=>'Designer', 'rate'=>'800', 'dayoff'=>'SUN'),
    '003' => array('id'=>'003', 'name'=>'david, sample', 'dept'=>'IT', 'position'=>'', 'rate'=>'220.83', 'dayoff'=>'SUN'),
    '004' => array('id'=>'004', 'name'=>'Test, Johny', 'dept'=>'', 'position'=>'', 'rate'=>'600', 'dayoff'=>''),
    '005' => array('id'=>'005', 'name'=>'Name, Last', 'dept'=>'IT', 'position'=>'Programmer', 'rate'=>'500', 'dayoff'=>'SUN')
);
```

When I compute their salary I grab all the details of employee`($users array)` from that file. This is my sample function.

```
function compute(){

global $users;
    include('users.php');
    //import list of users;

    foreach($the_log as $k=>$v){
            if($users[$k]){
            //codes here
            //show user data with computed salary
      }
   }

}
```

How can I make a simple database(like csv file or text file) not MySql or any open source database, so that I can add, edit and delete a user(with just a click) easily whenever I want. What I want to achieve here is to be able to make `$users` array editable. Is it possible?

**Edit:** When I use or save data in .csv file, How can I edit or delete a specific user/row?

Comment: Well you can make it with csv :)

Comment: You could use Php's `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv`.  Or `serialize`/`unserialize` manipulate your array and read/write to file.

Comment: @MuthaFury Any reference that I can follow on how to do it?

Comment: @c.k you Progrock answered your question :D. By using fgetcsv and fputcsv

Comment: Thanks. Gonna search for it.

Comment: I would go for SQLite. It is just a file (not a server) which you run proper SQL-queries against. Easy to use with PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I haven't tried SQLite. Just MySQL. Do I need to have a connection with it? If yes, I just gonna go with csv file because my system is just a simple one.

Comment: @Progrock Is there a way that I can add, delete, edit a row in csv file using php. Just like when adding or deleting data in MySQL database(query).

Comment: Yes, you need a connection. If you go with a flat file solution, the easiest way would probably be to load all users into an array, modify the user you want, replace that array element and save the full array to the file again. You could go for csv, json or something like that. With json, you only need to: `$users = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/users.json'));` to get all users.

Comment: If you don't want a database server, you want a file. Dealing with a file is simple: read it, manipulate the data, write it back.  What format you use in that file is up to you: JSON, CSV, plain text, YAML... there are serializers and deserializers for any possible format. SQLite also falls in this category. However, you will have to deal with concurrent access then, i.e. what happens when two instances want to write to the file at the same time. Is that a concern? If so, using a database may be the better solution, since that's a large part of what databases deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's fun, I created an example of how you could do it.

**Bare in mind, it's not tested so it might have some bugs but it shows how you could do it.**

Since you got so much finished code, I'll leave that up to you to find the bugs. ;-) (However, if you find bugs, leave them as a comment and I'll update the answer).

**Important note:** Just like @deceze mentioned in his comment, this works well if you know that there won't be any simultaneous "connections" (several people working with the files at the same time) and that you always "open, do stuff, save" and not "open, do stuff, open in a new browser tab, do stuff, save in first tab, save in second tab". Otherwise, your first changes will be overwritten with your second changes and so on...

#### Class to manage users:

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $users = [];

    /**
     * @param string    $path   Path to the user file (must be writeable)
     */
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->path  = $path;

        if (!is_file($this->path)) {
            // The file doesn't exist yet, let's create it
            file_put_contents($this->path, json_encode([]));

        } else {
            // It does exist. Load it.
            $this->users = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->path), true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all users
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function all()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * Get a specific user
     * 
     * @param  string|integer $userId   The array index for that user
     * @return array|null               Returns null if user doesn't exist
     */
    public function get($userId)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($userId, $this->users)) {
            // The key doesn't exist, return null
            return null;
        }

        return $this->users[$userId];
    }

    /**
     * Update or add a user
     * 
     * @param  string|integer $userId   The array index for that user
     * @param  array  $data             The user info
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function save($userId, array $data)
    {
        $this->users[$userId] = $data;

        $written = file_put_contents($this->path, json_encode($this->users));

        return $written !== false;
    }
}
```

#### How you would use it:

```
// When you have created the instance, use the same instance
// through out your whole application (only do: new Users() once). 
// You could do this with some factory class.
$users = new Users('/path/to/users.json');

// List all users
foreach($users->all() as $userId => $row) {
    echo $row['first_name'];
    // ...
}

// Get user
$user = $users->get('001');

// Change user
$user['first_name'] = "Magnus";

// Save user (this is both update and add)
$users->save('001', $user);
```